# Adding 3 way dimmer when two circuits exist

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 3 switches controlling ceiling cans.  I wish to replace one switch with a 3 way dimmer.  The box has 4 wires.  2 black. 2 red.  One black completes a circuit with one of the red wires.  The other black completes a circuit with the other red wire.

How do I connect a dimmer with one black and 2 red wires?

Thanks

Comment: Oops. Thought you said **fans**. You said **cans**. That should be easier! **Please upload pictures showing the existing switches/wires.**

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all switch boxes involved? Are these ceiling cans over a staircase, perchance?

Answer (score 1):

*(I am by no means any sort of expert, but I hope this points you in the right direction at least. I'm not an electrician but randomly looked up stuff about switches before because I was curious why they were called "3-way".)*

You mentioned that there are three switches controlling the lights. That means there are two 3-way switches and one 4-way switch. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#More_than_two_locations) on this does a much better job explaining than I can. Essentially you need 3-way switches to have two switches control one light, but you need 4-way switches to allow for more than two.

You said the switch you replaced has 4 wires. Sounds to me like you're looking at the 4-way switch from the middle of the circuit. I would guess you bought three 3-way dimmers and replaced the other two without issue but are confused with this one. I think you simply need a 4-way dimmer.

[image: Using three switches]

Comment: Thing is, 4-way dimmers are quite a non-trivial thing to do (it's possible by abusing a special type of dimmer + some relaying, but it's a hack all the same, and not up to current Code in situations where multiway switching is a Code req, not just a convenience function)